# Is front-running allowed under PFOF?

Tags: trading, limit-order, order-execution

I'm reading this introduction to PFOF.

https://centerpointsecurities.com/payment-for-order-flow-guide/

It claims that those buying flow are allowed to front-run that flow. For example, if a customer sends a buy order to $3 and the current best offer is $2.99, the HFT firm is allowed to buy in the lit market at $2.99 and then fill the customer at $3.

Is that legal? I thought that the HFT firm was required to give better-or-same as the current best offer?

Comment: Welcome new uers, Just two points, (1) there is the "averaging" thing at play (search down to 'bundle retail orders')  (2) also - so what?  You've "discovered" so to speak a hot issue.  It even mentions in that primer, "There is much controversy about the ramifications of order flow arrangements."  (Unfortunately) your observation would be like making a post "I've noticed that shockingly, congresspeople add items that favor *their own districts* to bills!"  :) you know?

Comment: That web site actually has a completely reasonable explanation of candles (https://centerpointsecurities.com/candlestick-charts/) which will be very handy for the endless questions on here like "how do I make 18% compound per month with candlestick charts and which broker should I use".  Good web site, bravo!